# Regex strong password the special characters

Tags: php, regex

I am currently making some tests with regex. I had an exercise which requested to check for a strong password, which means it should have: at least one number,one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, no spaces, and at least one
character that is not a letter or number. And it should be between 8-16 characters.

I wrote this code:

```
     <?php

  $passwords = array("Jtuhn", "12J@k", "jok", "Joan 12@45", "Jghf2@45", "Joan=?j123j");

  foreach($passwords as $pass)
  {
    ///^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$/
    if(strlen($pass) >= 8 && strlen($pass) < 17)
     {
       if(preg_match("/^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[^0-9A-Za-z])(?=\w*[a-z])\w*$/", $pass) )
        echo "$pass => MATCH<br>";
       else
        echo "$pass => FAIL<br>";
     }
    else
      echo "$pass => FAIL(because of length)<br>";
  }
 ?>
```

The last two should match but they fail. I think the problem stands at

```
(?=\w*[^0-9A-Za-z])
```

which is supposed to be the pattern match to have at least one character that is not a letter or a number, but I cant figure out why. 
I know this strong password is solved in internet but thats not my issue. My issue is why that part of work dont do what is supposed to do.

Comment: A strong password is an *unpredictable* password, while regular expressions check for *patterns*. If something follows a pattern, it can't be unpredictable ... Also, a 17-character password is stronger than a 16-character one, so that's a silly limitation.

Comment: @Narf well i think thats not a big deal.. My real problem is for the pattern. It is supposed that (?=\w*[^0-9A-Za-z]) check for special characters where order doesnt matter. But that doesnt work. If I remove it , than the patter validate the passwords well if they contain one uppercase letter , one lowercase letter and one digit. 
When I add that one , it doesnt validate nothing , all fail.

Comment: Your regex is `^\w*[lookaheads]\w*$`. It won't match anything that contains special characters, __and__ it's prone to catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Rawing why is that ? Should I remove anything from the regex ?

Comment: Your regex is essentially `^\w*\w*$` and `\w` doesn't match special characters. These `\w*` serve no purpose, so you can just remove them (along with the `$`). Then change all your lookaheads from `(?=\w*` to `(?=.*` and it will work.

Comment: Just trigger the lookahead assertions at start of string. Your main condition is to match 8-16 *non-space characters* `^\S{8,16}$` and add your conditions at `^` start [like this](https://regex101.com/r/OXagOM/1).

Comment: @Rawing why it works with (?=.* instead of (?=\w* ? Arent those the same ?

Comment: @JoanPlepi No, they're not the same. `(?=\w*\d)` won't match strings like `#2` but `(?=.*\d)` will.

Comment: please read about this in documentation *[`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/5340/password-validation-regex#t=201702261202089750805)*

Comment: Placing an upper limit on password length (especially as short as 16 characters) is a red flag that there's something wrong with the way you handle passwords; even if there isn't, it'll be perceived as such. Omit the restriction, or at least make the maximum much longer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could split your regex into different checks.

It will allow you to write more readable conditions and to display specific error messages. Although, regexp patterns will be easier to write and to understand.

i.e. :

```
$errors = array();
if (strlen($pass) < 8 || strlen($pass) > 16) {
    $errors[] = "Password should be min 8 characters and max 16 characters";
}
if (!preg_match("/\d/", $pass)) {
    $errors[] = "Password should contain at least one digit";
}
if (!preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $pass)) {
    $errors[] = "Password should contain at least one Capital Letter";
}
if (!preg_match("/[a-z]/", $pass)) {
    $errors[] = "Password should contain at least one small Letter";
}
if (!preg_match("/\W/", $pass)) {
    $errors[] = "Password should contain at least one special character";
}
if (preg_match("/\s/", $pass)) {
    $errors[] = "Password should not contain any white space";
}

if ($errors) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . "\n";
    }
    die();
} else {
    echo "$pass => MATCH\n";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it helped. Nice approach to find also which rules are broken from every string. Thanks

Comment: The regular expression you wrote for mathcing special characters is not accurate as the underscore (_) will not be recognized as a  special character by '\W'!. So, the optimal solution (as I see) is to use this regular expression to cover all the special characters: (?=\S*[^a-zA-Z0-9]) (except spaces).

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,16}$
```

It covers all your requirment

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/I2MK05/3)

1. `(?=.*\d)` Atleast a digit
2. `(?=.*[a-z])`  Atleast a lower case letter
3. `(?=.*[A-Z])` Atleast an upper case letter
4. `(?!.* )` no space
5. `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` at least a character except `a-zA-Z0-9`
6. `.{8,16}`  between 8 to 16 characters

Sample Code:

```
<?php
$re = '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,16}$/m';
$str = 'Jtuhn
12J@k
jok
Joan 12@45
Jghf2@45
Joan=?j123j
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/HTfgZE)

Comment: this worked very good thank you @Maverick_Mrt
^[a-zA-Z0-9] means expect a-zA-Z0-9. This [^a-zA-Z0-9]  is wrong ? Cause I read this one in a book thats why I wrote it...

Comment: @ Maverick_Mrt , I copy paste your regex: ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*^[a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,16}$ and it worked well
I just dont understand , [^a-zA-Z0-9] is wrong approach if I want to do expect a-zA-Z0-9 ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you [^A-Za-z0-9] means negated character class it will match anything which is not A-Z or a-z or 0-9 ... it is a completely valid syntax

Comment: @JoanPlepi had removed my comment because I thought it's clear from your comment already :) I thought the `^[a-zA-Z0-9]` was a typo. Maybe it worked because you tried in multiline mode.

Comment: This is good, but you should do away with the no white space regular expression and up the limit on the password length to at least 100. Passwords should be hashed which nullifies the need to restrict white space, and many people use password managers which can generate passwords up to 100 characters long. Not taking this into consideration allows hackers to narrow down password choices, giving them a better chance of brute forcing into an account.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}\S+$

//The rule is at least
   one upper case, one lower case, one digit[0-9], 
   one special character[#?!@$%^&*-] and the minimum length should be 8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple regex to test a strong password

```
/(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.{0,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z])(?=.{0,}\W)(?=.{0,}\d)/g
```

Javascript:

```
var password = "Abcdef@1234"
var passwordRegex = /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.{0,}[A-Z])(?=.{0,}[a-z])(?=.{0,}\W)(?=.{0,}\d)/g

var isStrongPassword = passwordRegex.test(password)

console.log(isStrongPassword, "<Strong password>")
```

1. Minimum length 8 characters
2. at least 1 uppercase
3. at least 1 lowercase
4. at least 1 special character
5. at least 1 digit

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[special characters]).{8,16}$
```

Add special characters as per requirement.

Above code check following conditions

- At least 1 uppercase character
- At least 1 lowercase character
- At least 1 digit
- At least 1 special character

[Click here to test](https://regex101.com/r/djGvFS/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code In PHP For a strong Password.
Password must have 8 characters and a mix of letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, and symbols :

```
$pswrdChk = 'Test@123';

if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,50}$/', $pswrdChk)) 
{
echo "Use at least 8 characters and a mix of letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, and symbols.";
}
else 
{
  echo "Password is Valid";
}
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!