# Add special characters and number in password symfony

Tags: symfony, passwords

For my project, I have to create Users and I would like to change the properties of the password. Symfony automaticcaly define 6 characters for it, but i would like to add special characters and number in it. For the length i'm fine, but for the rest i don't find the answers.

Here is my form

```
->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
```

Do you know if I change the properties in my form it will be enough?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Compound constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Compound.html)

So basically you would create your own "rules-set". In this case, for passwords.

In order to have at least one number (digit) or/and one special-char, you could use [Regex Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html). To be more precise - two of them:

- to match at least one digit
- to match at least one special char

```php
// src/Validator/Constraints/MyPasswordRequirements.php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Compound;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class MyPasswordRequirements extends Compound {

    protected function getConstraints(array $options): array
    {
        return [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\Length(['min' => 6]),
            //regex -> to have at elast one digit
            new Assert\Regex([
                'pattern' => '/\d+/i', 
            ]),
            //regex -> to have at elast one special char from the list
            //note: list of special-char is [#?!@$%^&*-]. Adjust to suite your needs
            new Assert\Regex([
                'pattern' => '/[#?!@$%^&*-]+/i', 
            ]),
        ];
    }
}
```

and then in your form just use this one `MyPasswordRequirements` constraint

```php
->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
    'constraints' => [
        new MyPasswordRequirements()
    ],
    // validation error message 
    'invalid_message' => 'Password requirements are not fulfilled'
])
```

**P.S.** I intentionally split reg-ex in two, just for better understanding and demonstration. I can combine them into one, and perhaps add further restrictions. Take as look at [Regex strong password the special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467243/regex-strong-password-the-special-characters)

Comment: Ok thanks it seems to work, but I would like to pop an error message if the password don't respect the rules. Should I put an error message per kind of characters, or just one for all and how can I do it?

Comment: @Mizerito75 see 'invalid_message' for all formtypes. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

from symfony 6.3 you can use the constraint [PasswordStrength](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/PasswordStrength.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
 #[Assert\PasswordStrength]
```